# Should I declare my body css with body {width:100%;}?

Tags: html, css

I want it to actually fit the entire screen, no matter the resolution.

Is it advisable to do it this way, or do I need to set the `px` for each and every resolution via media queries?

Comment: It's gonna be a 100% by default.

Comment: When does the body _not_ take up the entire screen? (Are you trying to reference margins and padding? [the whitespace surrounding child content within body])

Comment: It didn't seem like it was taking up the entire screen, until I just tried a CSS reset on the entire layout. Now it fits... doh!

Comment: @RenoYeo Fill body with some color and then you'll see it.

Comment: I can never understand why some people blatantly downvote questions... is it not helpful for newbies like me and others in future to understand that `body{width:100%;}` is redundant?

Comment: @RenoYeo This question is not showing any searching effort

Comment: @sandeep I searched for 'setting body tag to 100%'. there was nothing that claimed `width:100%` was redundant nor by default the `<body>` tag was a block element. If you want me to state what I searched for, I can always edit the question to contain it. Don't assume that I didn't search for anything and just came for answers.

Comment: If the display type of the body element is set to something else, such as `display: table` (which is not too uncommon), then setting the width to 100% becomes necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, your `body` element will fill the entire screen, you do not need to add any CSS.

Any element with `display: block`, which `body` has by default, will fill the width available.

Comment: so that being said -- there's no specific benefits to actually declaring `width:100%`?

Comment: @RenoYeo No benefits, just you becoming part of the redundancy for the redundancy departments redundancy.

Comment: No, there is no benefit in adding width:100% at all.

Comment: @CodingKiwi Right. Because I've seen some websites declaring it as 100% as well. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @RenoYeo You'll find *lots* of sites out there with redundant styles set (some less obvious than others) if you take the time to look.

Comment: @cimmanon well, then I'm glad you guys took the time to explain. Hopefully others will also learn to avoid such a declaration in future.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you should not use media queries to set the body's width. The body element inherits its width from the browser's viewport. So, it is enough to set *width:100%* and body's width will be always equal to the browser's viewport size. I.e. the width which you are interested in.

Comment: *So, it is enough to set width:100%*. This is also known as redundancy.